# Rhomobile Migration from Rho3.1 to Rho 4.0 Alert Msg. Error

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I am trying to migrate my rho application from 3.1 to 4.0. In 3.1 i have defined alert using `Alert.show_popup :title => "Please Wait", :message => "Fetching Data..."` But as specified in documentation now i have changed it to the

```
dataPopProps = Hash.new
dataPopProps['message'] = "Fetching Data...";
dataPopProps['title'] = "Please Wait";
Rho::Notification.showPopup(dataPopProps)
```

But i am still getting the same error.[image: Error Shown on mobile]
**Error: Button list has been incorrectly defined. DIalog will not Launch**

Any help will be great.

Comment: Solved this with giving buttons property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
 dataPopProps = Hash.new    
 dataPopProps['message'] = "Fetching Data...";
 dataPopProps['title'] = "Please Wait";    
 dataPopProps['buttons'] = ["Ok"]
 Rho::Notification.showPopup(dataPopProps)
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the official docs are often incorrect, so working with Rhodes can be frustrating. However, [the example listed here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/4.0.0/api/Notification#e1) seems to be a good solution. Note that the example for Notification is in Javascript.

Here is an elegant way to write this in Ruby:

```
dataPopProps = {
  'message' => 'Fetching Data...',
  'title'   => 'Please Wait',
  'buttons' => [{ :id => 'no', :title => 'no' }]
}
```

Semicolons are eggregiously unecessary in Ruby, and you can clean up your code by using literals instead of `Hash.new`.